# Trying to Call Multiple ActionCreators in Component using React Redux and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have two components, User and AppSettings. I'm trying to access their stores in the App component. I have tried several different things from reading react redux help docs, but I cannot figure out how to get my ***mapDispatchToProps*** function to work in App. The closest I get is the code below which throws the error ***TypeError: this.props.requestUser is not a function***

Does anyone know how I should structure my ***mapDispatchToProps*** to correctly import my actionCreators from two stores? Or do I have something else wrong and am hunting in the wrong spot? Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

**Error Screenshot**

```
  33 | }
  34 | 
  35 | private fetchUser() {
> 36 |     this.props.requestUser();
     | ^  37 | }
  38 | 
  39 | public render() {
```

**AppSettings.ts**

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';

// app settings state
export interface AppSettingsState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    appSettings: AppSettings;
}

export interface AppSettings {
    SiteTitle: string;
    PrimaryBackgroundColor: string;
    PrimaryFontColor: string;
    FooterLinkColor: string;
} 

// ACTIONS - descriptions of state transitions
interface RequestAppSettingsAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS';
}

interface ReceiveAppSettingsAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_APP_SETTINGS';
    appSettings: AppSettings;
}

/* Declare a 'discriminated union' type. */
type KnownAction = RequestAppSettingsAction | ReceiveAppSettingsAction;

// ACTION CREATORS - These are functions exposed to UI components that will trigger a state transition.
// They don't directly mutate state, but they can have external side-effects (such as loading data).

export const actionCreators = {
    requestAppSettings: (): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        /* Only load data if it's something we don't already have (and are not already loading) */
        console.log("AppSettings fired");
        const appState = getState();
        if (appState && appState.appSettings) {
            fetch(`appsettings`)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<AppSettings>)
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_APP_SETTINGS', appSettings: data });
                });

            dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS'});
        }
    }
};

/*
REDUCER - For a given state and action, returns the new state.
To support time travel, this must not mutate the old state.
*/

const unloadedState: AppSettingsState = {
    isLoading: false,
    appSettings: {
        SiteTitle: "",
        PrimaryBackgroundColor: "",
        PrimaryFontColor: "",
        FooterLinkColor: ""
    }
};

export const reducer: Reducer<AppSettingsState> = (state: AppSettingsState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): AppSettingsState => {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return unloadedState;
    }

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_APP_SETTINGS':
            return {
                appSettings: state.appSettings,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case 'RECEIVE_APP_SETTINGS':
            return {
                appSettings: action.appSettings,
                isLoading: false
            };
            break;
    }

    return state;
};
```

**User.ts**

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';
import * as Cookies from '../Utilities/cookies';

export interface UserState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    loginError: string;
    loggedIn: boolean;
    user: User;
}

export interface User {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    token: string
} 

interface RequestUserAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_USER';
}

interface ReceiveUserAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_USER';
    loginError: string;
    user: User;
}

type KnownAction = RequestUserAction | ReceiveUserAction;

export const actionCreators = {
    requestUser: (event?: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) : AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {

        const appState = getState();
        var url = "";
        var skip = false;
        var params = {};

        /* Two ways to get user info - they submitted the login form
         * or they are already logged in and have a user object cookie */

        if (event != undefined) {

            event.preventDefault();
            const target = event.target as typeof event.target & {
                username: { value: string };
                password: { value: string };
            };

            const username = target.username.value;
            const password = target.password.value;

            url = "user/login";
            params = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password })
            }

        } else {

            var cUser: string | null = Cookies.getCookie("user");
            if (cUser) {
                var user: User = JSON.parse(cUser);
                url = "user";
                params = {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
                    }
                }

            } else {
                skip = true; // home page and never has or tried to login
            }
        }

        if (appState && appState.user && !skip) {
            fetch(url, params)
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error(response.status.toString());
                    } else {
                        return response.json() as Promise<User>;
                    }
                })
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_USER', user: data, loginError: "" });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_USER', user: {} as User, loginError: error.message });
                });

            dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_USER' });
        }
    }
};

const unloadedState: UserState = {
    isLoading: false,
    loginError: "",
    loggedIn: false,
    user: {
        username: "",
        email: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        token: ""
    }
};

export const reducer: Reducer<UserState> = (state: UserState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): UserState => {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return unloadedState;
    }

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_USER':
            return {
                user: state.user,
                loginError: "",
                loggedIn: false,
                isLoading: true,
            };
        case 'RECEIVE_USER':

            var loggedIn = false;

            if (!action.loginError) {
                loggedIn = true;
                Cookies.setCookie("user", JSON.stringify(action.user), 7);
            } else {
                loggedIn = false;
                Cookies.eraseCookie("user");
            }

            return {
                user: action.user,
                loginError: action.loginError,
                loggedIn: loggedIn,
                isLoading: false
            };
            break;
    }

    return state;
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import FetchData from './components/FetchData';
import CapacityGrid from './components/CapacityGrid';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { ApplicationState } from './store';
import * as AppSettingsStore from './store/AppSettings';
import * as UserStore from './store/User';
import './css/custom.css'
import { userInfo } from 'os';

type AppSettingsProps =
    AppSettingsStore.AppSettingsState
    & typeof AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
 
type UserProps =
    UserStore.UserState
    & typeof UserStore.actionCreators

class App extends React.PureComponent<UserProps & AppSettingsProps & { children?: React.ReactNode }> {

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchAppSettings();
        this.fetchUser();
    }

    private fetchAppSettings() {
        this.props.requestAppSettings();
    }

    private fetchUser() {
        this.props.requestUser();
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {!this.props.isLoading &&
                    <Layout>
                        <Route path='/capacity-grid' component={CapacityGrid} />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/counter' component={Counter} />
                        <Route path='/fetch-data/:startDateIndex?' component={FetchData} />
                    </Layout>
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

}

/* works 
export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.user,
    UserStore.actionCreators
)(App as any); */

/*const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    userActions: () => dispatch(UserStore.actionCreators.requestUser),
    appActions: () => dispatch(AppSettingsStore.actionCreators.requestAppSettings),
});*/

const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
    user: state.user,
    appSettings: state.appSettings
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (
    UserStore.actionCreators,
    AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App as any);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I needed to use the spread operator to get both actionCreators in my **matchDispatchToProps**

I changed this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
    user: state.user,
    appSettings: state.appSettings
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (
    UserStore.actionCreators,
    AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
);
```

to this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
    ...state.user,
    ...state.appSettings
});

const mapDispatchToProps = ({
    ...UserStore.actionCreators,
    ...AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (
   UserStore.actionCreators,
   AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
);
```

is equivalent of

```
const mapDispatchToProps = AppSettingsStore.actionCreators
```

Meaning the User's action creator isn't being passed to App.ts. You should be able to verify this in React devtools as well.

Here's a small [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-kare-ww5qj) which pin points the problem.

To fix this, you'll need to define the `mapDispatchToProps` as you have commented out.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  userActions: () => dispatch(UserStore.actionCreators.requestUser),
  appActions: () => 
    dispatch(AppSettingsStore.actionCreators.requestAppSettings),
});
```